# How to get mu and sigma from a population containing multiples lognormal distributions

Tags: python, lognormal-distribution

Let's say that I have a data set that contains 3 different lognormal populations. How is the way to get each parameter (mu and sigma) from each population?

I am representing the problem as follows:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Generation of 3 population:
import numpy as np

s1 = np.random.lognormal(2, 0.6, 1000)  #mu and sigma
s2 = np.random.lognormal(1.6, 0.3, 1000) #mu and sigma
s3 = np.random.lognormal(1.8, 0.5, 1000) #mu and sigma

mb = np.max([s1,s2,s3])
X = np.arange(1,mb,1)
 #histogram population 1
Y11, bins1 = np.histogram(s1, X)
Y1 = Y11/Y11.sum()
X1 = bins1[:-1]

 #histogram population 2
Y22, bins2 = np.histogram(s2, X)
Y2 = Y22/Y22.sum()
X2 = bins2[:-1]

 #histogram population 3
Y33, bins3 = np.histogram(s3, X)
Y3 = Y33/Y33.sum()
X3 = bins3[:-1]

 #universe, with all mixed populations
S =  np.concatenate((s1, s2, s3), axis=None)


Yi, bins = np.histogram(S, X)
Y = Yi/Yi.sum()
X = bins[:-1]

def logN(x, mu, sigma):
      
    return  (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma **2)) / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))  #lognormal function

params, pcov = curve_fit(logN, X,Y, method="lm")
print(params)
plt.plot(X1, Y1, 'o')
plt.plot(X2, Y2, 'o')
plt.plot(X3, Y3, 'o')
plt.plot(X, Y, 'r-o')
plt.plot(X, logN(X ,params[0], params[1])) 

plt.show()
```

This code produces the fit for the global population, but I'm confusing what is the model to scale it to different populations. I know that this works for a sum of Gaussians distributions, but for lognormal I don't know how this works:
[image]

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Fit a Gaussian mixture model to the logarithms.  You can find several approaches (least squares, Bayes, etc.) along with working code in various threads here.